# Issue with audio codec in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

To my little knowledge i believe this is an audio codec issue however since im not really familiar with ffmpeg, anything could be wrong.

```
  W:\PICTURES\\Manual Files>ffmpeg -i "C7984.mp4" -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:06:00 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 C7984%03d.mp4

ffmpeg version 2021-07-11-git-79ebdbb9b9-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.3.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  3.101 / 59.  3.101
  libavformat    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.103 /  8.  0.103
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001f2b61fe100] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 1001
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001f2b61fe100] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 1001.
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C7984.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : XAVC
    minor_version   : 16785407
    compatible_brands: XAVCmp42iso2
    creation_time   : 2021-07-09T18:30:52.000000Z
  Duration: 00:07:07.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 207012 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le(pc), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 200015 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-09T18:30:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-09T18:30:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (rtmd / 0x646D7472), 5401 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-09T18:30:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Timed Metadata Media Handler
      timecode        : 23:59:04:56
[segment @ 000001f2b6729440] Opening 'C7984000.mp4' for writing
[mp4 @ 000001f2b4627ec0] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16be in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:2 --
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Should the code be changed to convert the audio to flac prior to convert the clip? thanks

Answer (score 0):

MP4s don't support PCM, but MOVs do. MP4s do support AAC.

So, either

`ffmpeg -i "C7984.mp4" -c copy -c:a aac -map 0 -segment_time 00:06:00 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 C7984%03d.mp4`

or

`ffmpeg -i "C7984.mp4" -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:06:00 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 C7984%03d.mov`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Flac is lossless and you have to do it

Get first the audio in flac

```
ffmpeg -i "C7984.mp4" -map 0:1 -c:a flac audio.flac
```

---

Get the only the video in mp4, option -an is audio none...

```
ffmpeg -i "C7984.mp4" -map 0:0 -c copy -an -dn video.mp4
```

---

Now create a new video with the same video and flac lossless audio from pcm_s16be stream of C7984.mp4 video...

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a flac -i audio.flac -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a:0   -disposition:a:0 default  -disposition:a:1 default  -strict -2 -sn -dn -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1  -movflags faststart fin_video_flac.mp4
```

---

NOTE: if you want CUT THE VIDEO like a video from min 6, now you can cut the new video, the -ss option is the start of the video, and the duration is de option -t

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:06:00 -i fin_video_flac.mp4  -t 60 -c copy -strict -2 final_video_60seconds.mp4
```

---

regards